# Организация коллективного доступа через Delphi 7 к dbf

Tags: delphi, база-данных, dbf

Здравствуйте, друзья.

Требуется помощь в вопросе, указанном в заголовке, если конкретно, то ситуация следующая:
Лет так 5 назад была написана программа, которая осуществляет формирование электронных отчетов на основании данных со склада. Программисты не смогли организовать коллективный доступ к базам данных, так что создали 3 копии программы и 3 БД с разными названиями и одинаковым содержимым. При запуске программа сверяет все базы данных, актуализирует свою базу и дальше работает с ней. Всё бы ничего, и эти костыли прошли бы незамеченными, если бы не понадобилось сделать ещё несколько копий программы, а конкретно - 4, то есть организовать доступ с 7 компьютеров. Вот тут стал вопрос, что если раньше при запуске проводилось 3 проверки между базами данных, то теперь их будет 36, что скажется как на производительности, так и на степени актуальности данных.

Вопрос такой: есть ли сайт, на котором доступным языком изложено, как организовать коллективный доступ, желательно так, чтобы понял я, человек, который пишет на Delphi второй раз в жизни. И вообще, какие будут предложения по поводу этой работы, кроме вполне очевидного "прекратить насиловать труп"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Программисты не смогли организовать коллективный доступ к базам данных". Причем здесь программисты? Они же занимаются, извините, но других слов нет, онанизмом 5 лет!!! И осталось желание продолжать до бесконечности!

Что значит не могут? Задача для школьника - объединить 3+4 ПК в сеть.

1. Только коллективный доступ (системный администратор).
2. Переписать обработку, используя только SQL. На Delphi легко, используя ADO.
3. Перенести таблицы c данными в БД, например, MS SQL Server.
4. Заниматься делом.

**Обновление**

Как временная мера (до пятницы). Прописать в приложениях путь к таблицам на файл сервере. Не помню, есть ли на  Clipper транзакции, но можно обойтись и блокировками, т.е., перед каждой командой, изменяющей данные, установить блокировку и снимать ее по завершению. Но это путь в никуда.
Кстати, ODBC и OLEDB драйвера поддерживают SQL для DBF. Иначе я бы не писал об этом.

Comment: Программисты давно уволились, а я мне приходится разгребать за ними следы жизнедеятельности. Сеть между компьютерами есть, вся проблема состоит в том, что эта так называемая программа не даёт нескольким людям работать одновременно. На SQL пересадить вряд ли получится, так как у нас все базы работают ещё через Clipper, а он поддерживает формат только dbf. Весь вопрос в том-то и состоит, как к пятнице исправить этот косяк при наличии минимума знаний на Delphi.

Comment: Мне проще будет потом на java всё это переписать, но до пятницы точно не успеть. Можете посоветовать какой-нибудь источник, где можно подробнее почитать?

Comment: В принципе, используя SQL, язык не критичен. Но "до пятницы"... Почему не использовать тот же Clipper, изменив готовое приложение, как я писал выше?Просто не представляю объем работы.

Comment: Тут в чём загвоздка, у нас весь завод работает через Clipper, и только один отдел решил повыделываться и запилил себе программу на Delphi. Пересадить на SQL не представляется возможным, так как придётся переписывать оч-чень много программ, и действительно проще переписать эту программу на Клиппере, вот только я пытаюсь понять, не быстрее ли будет исправить уже готовое.

Comment: Тут - без вариантов -исправлять готовое. Но ориентироваться, в будущем, надо не на язык, а на СУБД. Клиентские приложения можно писать на любом. Что касается литературы, то, в общем случае, лучше 12 правил Кодда я не встречал. 12 строк и все понятно.

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос такой: есть ли сайт, на котором
> доступным языком изложено, как
> организовать коллективный доступ,
> желательно так, чтобы понял я,
> человек, который пишет на Delphi
> второй раз в жизни. И вообще, какие
> будут предложения по поводу этой
> работы, кроме вполне очевидного
> "прекратить насиловать труп"?

Прекратите насиловать труп. 
Надо переписывать и ПО и архитектуру сети.

Организовать сеть так, чтобы N компов все видели 1 серверный комп. N компов может хоть 7, хоть 25 - уже не имеет значения, расширяйтесь, пока не задолбает. :)

На серверную машину поставить любую СУБД, FireBird, MySQL, PostgreeSQL, MariaDB, имеющую разграничение прав и многопользовательский доступ. Я перечислил бесплатные.

Далее написать ПО административного уровня, т.е. видит всех и вся (а-ля начальник), создает рабочие места для сотрудников (логин/пароль, отчетность по работникам и т.д.).

Написать ПО локального уровня, ставится на комп сотрудника. Все. Сотрудник логинится, и все они успешно работают одновременно с базой без геморроя.

P.S. Из перечисленных СУБД порекомендую FireBird, т.к. бесплатна, функциональна, безболезненно и прозрачно можно научить работать в режиме встроенной БД (когда сеть пропала, данные идет пользователю на ЖД). Поддерживает возможность одовременного чтения-записи в таблицу разными юзерами. Крайне функциональная СУБД. А ещё [можно конвертить DBF формат в FB](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/datapump/index.asp), вам останется слить все базы в одну, подключить и наслаждаться.

Comment: Сейчас у нас в сети работает порядка 250 компьютеров, всё организовано через Clipper, и прекрасно, ну, удовлетворительно, работает. Вопрос был, скорее, не в организации как таковой, а в написании костыля, который поможет продержаться до следующего года, пока мы полностью не перейдем на новую систему.